# Document Upload and show as a link

Tags: contentdocument

We have a word file whose size is 15 MB and want to download it thorugh a link from Home page. However, as the standard document tab can only accept till 5 MB document size, it is not fulfilled.

Could you please let us know the alternative way to do it? Have loaded this document as Content in content section of salesforce, will it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can either:
contacting salesforce and requesting for the file size to be increased to 15mb rather than 5mb.
Or:
Attach the file to the notes and attachment section of SObjects where limit is 25 MB

Answer (score 0):

Using Content (or Files if Chatter is enabled) is the recommended way to store files.  There is a 2 GB limit for these files.

I'm not sure which method you want to use to display links on the home page, but you should be able to either use 'custom links' to link to a file, or add a visual force component to the home page which displays files.

If you use Salesforce Content, access to the file will be based on membership in the library the file belongs to.  If Chatter is enabled, you can easily share the file with the company, even if it is in a Content Library.

Please let me know if you need more information, and if so, please let me know if Chatter is enabled.